# Contacting family of Unteroffizier Wilhelm Braatz shot down in Battle of Britain?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

Passed down to me is a service cap of a pilot of the Luftwaffe from WW2. During the battle of Britain in September 1940 an aircraft flew over east Sussex smoke pouring out behind. The service cap was seen to fall out the aircraft and when picked up it had the name Braatz inside. Unfortunately he was killed when his aircraft crashed near Tonbridge and is now buried at Cannock chase. I would like to contact any of his family and perhaps return this cap to them. Wilhelm Braatz was born in Potsdam, Germany on 31/12/1919 and died 30/09/1940. He was posted to Guines airfield in France August 1940. There is a photo of him with four other officers wearing the cap I now have and would like to return.

Comment: You might check directories like [Das Örtliche](http://www.dasoertliche.de/) to contact possible relatives (people with that surname) in and around Potsdam. As Wilhelm Braatz died at a young age, descendants are less likely. Even other relatives might not be familiar with him or might have little interest in the service cap. If you don't want to keep it, consider giving it to a local museum together with your research on this matter. It might be better preserved there.

Comment: @lejonet I think that's enough info for an answer.

Comment: Maybe you could try contacting a genealogy circle in Postdam. They should have the skills and motivation to find whomever relatives are still alive.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Lejonet](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/contacting-family-of-unteroffizier-wilhelm-braatz-shot-down-in-battle-of-britain/14483#comment19679_13448):

> You might check directories like [Das
>   Örtliche](http://www.dasoertliche.de/) to contact possible relatives
>   (people with that surname) in and around Potsdam. As Wilhelm Braatz
>   died at a young age, descendants are less likely. Even other relatives
>   might not be familiar with him or might have little interest in the
>   service cap. If you don't want to keep it, consider giving it to a
>   local museum together with your research on this matter. It might be
>   better preserved there.